# What exactly is the difference between a data mapper and a repository?

Tags: orm, repository, repository-pattern, datamapper, domain-model

Well I've been trying to find out the difference between data mapper and repository, but up to now I still have not. It seems to me that the expert programmer said "Repository is another layer of abstraction over the mapping layer where query construction code is concentrated". It seems understandable but is still somewhat very abstract. I read this article on stackoverflow before, and it just made me even more confused:
[How is the Data Mapper pattern different from the Repository Pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550690/how-is-the-data-mapper-pattern-different-from-the-repository-pattern)

I guess what I need are simple explanations and concrete/practical examples on how the two patterns differ, and what a repository does what a data mapper doesnt, and vice versa. Do anyone of you know a good example on illustrating the concept of data mapper and repository? It will be better if it's the same example, just one using data mapper and another using repository. Thanks, I'd very appreciate this. I am still very confused as of now...

Answer (score 59):

Suppose your application manages `Person` objects, with each instance having `name`, `age` and `jobTitle` properties.

You would like to persist such objects, retrieve them from the persistence medium and maybe update (say, on their birthday, increment the age) or delete. These tasks are usually referred to as CRUD, from Create, Read, Update and Delete.

It is preferable to decouple your "business" logic from the logic that deals with the persistence of `Person` objects. This allows you to change the persistence logic (e.g. going from a DB to a distributed file system) without affecting your business logic.

You do this by encapsulating all persistence logic behind a `Repository`. A hypothetical `PersonRepository` (or `Repository<Person>`) would allow you to write code like this:

```
Person johnDoe = personRepository.get(p=> p.name == "John Doe");
johnDoe.jobTitle = "IT Specialist";
personRepository.update(johnDoe);
```

This is just business logic and doesn't care about how and where the object is stored.

On the other side of the `Repository`, you use both a `DataMapper` and something that translates queries from the functional description (`p=> p.name == "John Doe"`) to something that the persistence layer understands.

Your persistence layer can be a DB, in which case the `DataMapper` converts a `Person` object to and from a row in a `PersonsTable`. The query translator then converts the functional query into `SELECT * FROM PersonsTable WHERE name == "John Doe"`.

Another persistence layer can be a file system, or another DB format that chooses to store `Person` objects in two tables, `PersonAge` and `PersonJobTitle`.

In the latter case, the `DataMapper` is tasked with converting the `johnDoe` object into 2 rows: one for the `PersonAge` table and one for the `PersonJobTitle` table. The query logic then needs to convert the functional query into a `join` on the two tables. Finally, the `DataMapper` needs to know how to construct a `Person` object from the query's result.

In large, complex systems, you want to use small components that do small, clearly defined things, that can be developed and tested independently:

- The business logic deals with a `Repository` when it wants to read or persist objects, and doesn't care how that is *implemented*.
- The `Repository` deals with a `DataMapper` when it wants to read/write an object in a particular persistence medium.
- For querying, the `Repository` relies on a schema provided by the `DataMapper` (e.g. the `jobTitle` value is found in the `JobTitle` column in the `PersonTable` table) but not on any *implementation* of a mapper.
- For DB persistence, the `DataMapper` relies on a *DB layer*, that shield it from the Oracle/Sybase/MSSQL/OtherProvider details.

The patterns don't "differ", they just expose different basic features.

Comment: I see, thanks for your explanation. I think the Repository is an abstraction layer between the business object(Model) and data access object(DataMapper), is this a reasonable way to interpret this?

Comment: +1 I was wraping my head around these concepts for hours, trying to get an overall vision to design my model layer... It all suddenly becomes so clear with your clear and simple answer. Thank you !

Comment: Data mappers interact with databases, but don't necessarily have complex querying capabilities. Repositories expose/implement higher-level querying capabilities.

Answer (score 52):

I realize that this answer is kind of late, but it may help someone in the future that stumbles upon this same question and finds that the available answer(s) do not quite answer the question (which I felt when I first came across this question).

After having read PoEAA (Martin Fowler), I too was having trouble identifying the difference between a data mapper and a repository.

This is what I've found that the 2 concepts ultimately boil down to:

- a **Repository** acts like a collection of domain objects, with powerful querying capabilities (Evans, DDD)
- a **DataMapper** "moves data between objects and a database while keeping them independent of each other and the mapper itself" (Fowler, PoEAA)

**Repositories** are a generic concept and don't necessarily have to store anything to a database, its main function is to provide collection like (query-enabled) access to domain objects (whether they are gotten from a database is besides the point). Repositories may (and often will) contain DataMappers themselves.

**DataMappers** serve as the middle layer between domain objects and a database, allowing them to evolve independently without any one depending on the other. Datamappers might have "find" or query functionality, but that is not really their main function. The more you find that you are using elaborate query logic in your DataMappers, the more you want to start thinking about decoupling that query logic into a repository while leaving your DataMappers to serve their main function, mapping domain objects to the database and vice versa.